# The limit of $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{\frac1k}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

While playing around with some sequences, I came across the following problem:

Decide wether the limit of the sequence $\left(x_n\right)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ given by:
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{\frac1k}
$$
exits and if so, calculate it.

Under the assumption that the limit indeed exists, I proved that it is $2$:

Lower bound:
$$
x_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n}n^{\frac1k}=1+\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^{n}n^{\frac1k}≥1+\frac{n-1}{n}\implies\\
x:=\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n≥2
$$
For the upper bound I proved that:
$$
x_{mn}≤\frac{1}{mn}\left[\left(\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\exp\left(\frac{\log(mn)}{r}\right)\right)-(m-1)\exp\left(\frac{\log(mn)}{mn}\right)\right]+\left(mx_n\right)^\frac{1}{m}
$$
Under the assumption that the limit exists, we can consider $n\to\infty$ which yields:
$$
x≤1+\left(mx\right)^\frac{1}{m}
$$
By then considering $m\to\infty$ this implies $x≤2$ and thus $x=2$.

But I cannot think of an approach to show the existence of $x$. The sequence seems to be monotone decreasing for $n≥13$ which suggests to use induction, but to relate $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$ seems extremely hard. How can it be proven?

Thanks in advance.

Ps: If it helps, I can add the prove of the upper bound, just comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can split the sum

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n n^{\frac{1}{k}} &= 1 + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{2 \leqslant k \leqslant n^{1/3}} n^{\frac{1}{k}} + \frac{1}{n}\sum_{n^{1/3} < k \leqslant n} n^{\frac{1}{k}}\\
&\leqslant 1 + \frac{1}{n}\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot n^{1/3} + \frac{n - \lfloor n^{1/3}\rfloor}{n}\cdot n^{1/(n^{1/3})}\\
&\leqslant 1 + n^{-1/6} + n^{1/(n^{1/3})},
\end{align}

where the second term converges to $0$, and the third to $1$ since $\frac{\log n}{n^{1/3}} \to 0$, showing

$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k = 1}^n n^{\frac{1}{k}} \leqslant 2.$$